# Google static map API getting 403 forbidden when loading from img tag

Tags: image, api, google-maps, static

What I have is a Google map that shows the location of a property but when I come to print the dynamic maps dont print so good so I decided to implement the Google Static Map image API.

http://lpoc.co.uk/properties-for-sale/property/oldgate-dairy-st-james-road-long-sutton-cambridgeshire-pe12/?prop-print=1

^^ is an example of a property in print view and should show a static map image but it fails to load and looking at my inspector I'm getting a 403 Forbiden response for the image.

But if I go to the URL directly the image loads...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops I feel like such an idiot. I was using the old V2 maps API URL and not the new V3 API URL. I was getting a 403 because I was using the V2 URL without providing an API key :(

Comment: But even so, how comes that you get 403 when loading from an img tag, and it works when loading directly in the browser?? I have the same issue

Comment: And by the way, what V3 api url???? According to the documentation, there no such a thing as a static map api V3, the latest version for static map api is V2. I'm confused

Answer (score 18):

This has gotten quite a lot of views, so I'm adding my solution to the problem here:

When using the new API, make sure you generate a Key for browser apps (with referers) and also make sure the patterns match your URL.

E.g. when requesting from **example.com** your pattern should be

```
  example.com/*
```

When you're requesting from **www.example.com**:

```
  *.example.com/*
```

So make sure you check whether a subdomain is present and **allow both patterns** in the developer console.

1. Visit the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/static-maps-backend.googleapis.com/credentials).
2. Under API Keys, click the pencil icon to edit.
3. Under "Key restrictions", ensure that you have an entry for `example.com/*`, `*.example.com/*`, and any local testing domains you might want.

Comment: This is exactly what helped me! I spent whole weekend with that issue. Newest static maps api, right URL, I am sending api_key, api console told me "no problems" - and I was getting only error 403 forbidden by Google. Finally I found your advice and bingo! :) I've just added mydomain.com/* to api console and it works like a charm! Thank you :)

Comment: Also remember to add localhost/* if you want it to work on localhost

Comment: Is it possible to edit a project in the developer console, or do you have to delete the current one and add another?

Comment: I was eventually able to edit a project, but only from this URL: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key

Answer (score 14):

There seems to be some confusion here, and since this thread is highly ranked on Google, it seems relevant to clarify.

Google has a couple of different API's to use for their maps service:

#### Javascript API

The old version of this API was version 2, which required a key. This version is deprecated, and it is recommended to upgrade to the newer [version 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Note that the documentation still states that you need a key for this to function, except if you're using "Google Maps API for Business".

#### Static Maps API

This is a whole different story. Static maps is a service that does not require any javascript. You simply call an url, and Google will return a maps image, making it possible to insert the URL directly into your `<img>` tag.
The newest version is [version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), and **this requires a key** to function because a usage limit is applied.

A key can be requested here:
https://code.google.com/apis/console

And the key should be added to the request for the correct image to be generated:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&key=API_console_key`

I hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: I dunno if this has changed since your answer, but according to the static maps API v2 a key is not required. quoted from the site: "Note that the use of a key is not required, though it is recommended. Examples in this document do not include the key parameter so that they will work for all users who cut-and-paste the code."

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem but my solution was different.  I had the V2 maps api enabled, but not the static maps api (I thought this was V2).  I enabled the static maps api and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me.  In the [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) I had enabled "Google Maps API" but not "Static Maps API", which is near the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Be hundred percent sure of these points: (for static maps)

1. Enable your project at this url :

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/overview?project=

2. You have your localhost, staging and production - all urls with wildcards enabled in the referrer section.
3. Google has changed its policy and you now need an api key to display maps. refer this for more : [Google Maps API without key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148097/google-maps-api-without-key)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "the referrer section"?  As best I can tell, a "project" consists of only a name - there's nothing in the UI to tie a project to a particular website.

Comment: Update: "the referrer section" is located under "Credentials", and you can only enter specific domains (with wildcards) once you add "Key restriction" via "HTTP referrers (web sites)"

Answer (score 2):

Staticmaps V3 doesn't need the "Key" attribute and removing it seems to solve the `<img>` source problem.

**Try with an URL like this:**

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0.0000,0.0000&zoom=13&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=0.0000,0.0000&sensor=false
```

For more information [read this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Comment: I know this answer is old but future readers note that the linked doc states "This document details the Maps Static API v2". It also suggests that a key must be provided: `&key=YOUR_API_KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Google Maps API version 3 were java-script version; "Google Static Maps" latest were 2.0. I suspect there might be some restriction on use.

Answer (score 1):

I could also not display static maps and could see 403 error in the browser's network console.

http response headers:

```
status:403
x-content-type-options:nosniff
```

I had an API key with a lot of Google Maps APIs enabled but the `Google Static Maps API` was missing, enabling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

now you should use 'signature' parameter, which you should add to request - otherwise static maps won't work.
here is few useful links

1) [how to generate signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#generating_valid_signatures)

2) [how to make signature on BE side (code snippet)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#sample-code-for-url-signing)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Wordpress 4.9.4 with ChurchThemes Exodus Theme. I had applied for & generated a New API_KEY.

- I confirmed it was being used when calling the map:
  [Google Map Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqu5N.jpg)
- However the Js Console showed the following error:
  [Google Maps Error in Js Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhfba.png)
- As Johnny White mentioned above I had to navigate to the API Library Screen via APIs & Services Menu:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh7us.jpg)
- You will be greeted by the API Library screen:
  [API Library Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGLF1.png)
- Click on Maps(17) Lower LHS.
- Search for & click Google Static Maps API - Enable it if needed:
  [Google Static Maps API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULdr.png)
- You may also need to enable Google Maps Javascript API (same process as for Static Maps:
  [Google Maps Javascript API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHhOw.png)

Once that is done your maps should start appearing on your site or app.

If they don't appear on refresh you may need to:

- clear your cache (Wordpress or Drupal webistes),
- wait the 5 min recommended for the API to Register the enabled API's

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling billing on this Google Cloud Project/Firebase Project.

I was experiencing this same issue and just received the `403 error` in the console.
Copying and pasting the Static Maps URL in to the URL bar and loading it showed the following error message:

```
The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at 
https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As of this date, this answer led to solving my challenge with a 403. I had billing enabled but did not have the Static API enabled, which activates the billing for this service.